# Man who answers a ringing payphone is told about a imminent nuclear attack on North America

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama, action

Midnight, small diner in a large city, possibly Chicago or New York, an adult male sits and drinks his coffee. A couple others in coffee shop going about their business. He pays for his coffee and leaves. He walks out on to the dark street and hears the pay phone ringing. He doesn't want to answer but the phone just keeps ringing. Finally he picks it up without speaking, the guy on the other end begins to speak of a nuclear attack that is coming in a couple hours. After listening the guy is convinced it's for real. He decides only to tell his loved ones and starts calling them one by one, trying to arrange an evacuation ASAP. They spend most of the night trying to get away from the threat.

Which movie is this?

Comment: Can you tell us about when this came out? Any prominent actors? TV or Bigscreen?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the movie called [Miracle Mile](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097889/).

> A young man hears a chance phone call telling him that a nuclear war has started and missiles will hit his city in 70 minutes.
>
> A young man meets and falls in love with a young woman at the La Brea Tar Pits in Los Angeles. This area is known as Miracle Mile, and the whole movie takes place there. They make a date, which he misses, and while he is searching for her, he accidentally finds out that we (the United States) are about to start a nuclear war with the Soviet Union. He frantically searches for her so that they can escape Los Angeles.

Comment: Definately Miracle Mile . . .